# How can I get all of the properties related to one node type?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I have a node Country. I know that this node has some properties, but I don't know which. I mean, I know since I've take a look at model. Here is what I've found in documentation:

```
Country
name: String
iso_2_code: String 
iso_3_code: String 
region: String 
sub.region: String
```

I know that if I run

```
MATCH (c:Country)
RETURN c.iso_2_code
```

I'll get result for one specific property. Is there a query that would as a result return me something like: `name, iso_2_code, iso_3_code, region, sub.region`?

If I didn't have access to the model how could I list all of the properties that are attached to some node type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering more from a Cypher or openCypher perspective than for a specific implementation. Using the air-routes dataset. There are three things to consider.

Firstly if you know the properties you want, as you mentioned, you can just ask for them explicitly.

```
MATCH (a:airport {icao:'KDFW'})
RETURN a.city, a.desc
```

However, if you want all properties, but do not want to list them all, you can just do:

```
MATCH (a:airport {icao:'KDFW'})
RETURN properties(a)
```

If you just want the property keys:

```
MATCH (a:airport {icao:'KDFW'})
RETURN keys(properties(a))
```

Lastly, if you want the properties plus the label and ID information you can just do:

```
MATCH (a:airport {icao:'KDFW'})
RETURN a
```

Comment: Thanks! This are all useful thing for me since I'm new to Cypher. keys () is the thing that I was looking for!